# Triggered reputation recalc, lost ~500 reputation

Tags: support, reputation-recalc

I triggered a rep recalc and lost about 500 reputation (on Stack Overflow). How can I understand where I lost that rep? I can't see deleted posts.

Comment: You never had that rep to begin with.  It was all an illusion.  Why, if it wasn't for all my rep recalcs, I'd be beating the crap out of Jon Skeet's rep.  Oh, yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reputation can decrease for example because of

- Upvoted answers you gave to questions that have since been deleted
- Upvoted questions of yours that have since been deleted
- Upvotes you received from users whose accounts have since been deleted

in my experience, a 500 loss is pretty normal with a 5-digit reputation.

Comment: Deleted answers include those migrated to other sites.

Comment: okay, just so sad to become pushed behind 20k. :)

Comment: @Andrey never mind, those are quickly regained :)

Comment: @Andrey, note that *before* a recalc, the reputation report already shows you the numbers you would get *after* hitting the recalc button. Hence, if you had known that, then you also could have waited until the report showed a total above 20k.

Comment: @Arjan i didn't like the report. too much numbers :) anyway that is not that serious issue. thanks for hint, would know next time.

Comment: I guess curious folks must do (or schedule) a daily download of the report, to catch most of the differences, @Andrey.

Answer (score 4):

You lost 130 reputation from [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646745/is-it-magic-or-what/2646775#2646775), and 80 more from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874224/what-are-the-practical-concrete-application-of-net-4-0-enhancements/2874247#2874247), plus sundry others.

Comment: I'm happy to see you following through and increasing your participation on meta!  Thanks, and congrats on the win.

Comment: yeah, first one was really stupid. i don't regret.